# How to coordinate passing the data between 2 different scripts?

Tags: python

I Have python (3.6) script A.py, that calls script B.py (python 2).

I wanted to pass a list (1000+ float values) to the script B as argument but that did not work so I'm using pickle. It works fine.

Script B does its calculations and returns the result.

How to pass the result back to script A ? 
And how to make still running script A wait for the result ?

Comment: impossible to answer the last part without seeing how you run your code, but as for the first part, why not use pickle there too?

Comment: You could do a third script (main.py) which will call script B and script A functions

Comment: will the following options help ?

 [1]. create a function inside the Script A which accepts the list as argument and does the calculation on the list

 [2]. convert the python2 script to python3 syntax and put the function inside a class > create a package and include both files in it > import the script B in script A and create an object of the class present in script B and then use the function to get the results.

Comment: Why does passing the list as an argument not work?

Comment: @MAO3J1m0Op I am getting an error that the command is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility:

A.py could invoke B.py by using `Popen` in module `subprocess` setting the `stdout` parameter to `subprocess.PIPE`:

```
import subprocess

command = ['B.py', 'argument-1', 'argument-2', ..., 'argument-n']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate() # (stdout, stderr) as bytes
results = output[0].decode() # stdout as a string
```

Script B.y would simply print its output to `stdout`. This could be a `json` string if the results are structured. The input to B.y can also be, for example, a `json` string that B.y would read from `stdin`:

```
import subprocess

command = ['B.py']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
json = '{"x": 1, "y": 2}'
json_as_bytes = json.encode()
output = p.communicate(input=json_as_bytes) # (stdout, stderr) as bytes
results = output[0].decode() # stdout as a string
```